# button onclick from a layout file

Tags: android, xml, listview

so I was working on some basics of android when I stumbled upon this. I am trying to  implement a listview(having its layout stored in file eachrow.XML)and a button on my app such that when the user clicks one button "schoollife", the listview automatically imports layout stored from other file "eachrow2.XML".
the layout of eachrow.xml consists of buttons only, while the layout of eachrow2.xml consists of buttons.
Everything seems to work fine, the user clicking the button imports the other layout , but the problem starts when user tries to click buttons from the **second** layout. in the error logs, it is stating that the *button 'subject' causing a null pointer exception*

eachrow.xml:
[image]

eachrow2.xml:[image]

===========codes========
eachrow2.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subjectbutton"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"

            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/marksbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="click the button to show marks of each subject"
            android:textAlignment="center"

    />


</LinearLayout>
```

mainactivity.java:
    package com.example.ansh.reportcard;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private ListView l;
    private String[] d_myself;
    private ArrayAdapter adp;
    private HashMap<String,String> d_school;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.a_list);
        d_myself= new String[]{"something"
        };
        d_school=new HashMap<>();
        d_school.put("A","B");



        Button B_myself= (Button)findViewById(R.id.myself);
        B_myself.setOnClickListener(this);


        Button B_school=(Button)findViewById(R.id.school);
        B_school.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button subject=(Button)findViewById(R.id.subjectbutton);
        subject.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.myself){
            adp=new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.eachrow,R.id.textView,d_myself);
            l.setAdapter(adp);
        }
        if (view.getId()==R.id.school){
            adp=new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.eachrow2,R.id.subjectbutton,d_school.keySet().toArray());
            l.setAdapter(adp);
        }
        if (view.getId()==R.id.subjectbutton){
            Button  tmp=(Button)view;
            CharSequence x=tmp.getText();

            TextView t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marksbox);
            t.setText(d_school.get(x.toString()));

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: please add error log

Comment: I more confused by the question and/or error than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding to your question, You declaring the Button from the xml file activity_main.xml, Instead you should find it from the eachrow2.xml file.

The subjectbutton is in the eachrow2.xml so you need to find the view from this file only instead activity_main.xml.